# How to make pgfgantt scale to specific widths in the page? (ex. textwidth)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, charts

I'm trying to use pgfgantt to create a gantt chart for a project spanning many weeks, thus the following code would overflow through the right margin. I can't find a way to alter the size of the grid elements or time slots:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
\begin{ganttchart}%
[vgrid, hgrid]{50} % 50 weeks
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{5}{6} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{6} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{7}{11}
\ganttlink{4}{2}{5}{3}
\ganttlink[b-m]{6}{3}{6}{4}
\ganttlink[m-b]{6}{4}{7}{5}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**My former question above, however here's a new angle...**

How can I make pgfgantt scale everything by limiting its size to specific parameters? ex. I want it to span the full textwidth of the page or the full width save for the margins.

Comment: Could you turn your code snippet into a compilable document by adding the necessary preamble and `\begin{document}`?

Answer (score 16):

With command `\resizebox{new width}{new height}{what you want to resize}` you can change dimensions of any latex box. This means that everything (text, lines, simbols, ...) will be adjusted to new dimensions. In first or second parameter you can use `!` in order to keep original aspect ratio. With this command,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
\begin{ganttchart}%
[vgrid, hgrid]{50} % 50 weeks
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\    
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\    
\ganttbar{Task 2}{5}{6} \\    
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{6} \\    
\ganttbar{Task 3}{7}{11}
%\ganttlink{4}{2}{5}{3}
%\ganttlink[b-m]{6}{3}{6}{4}
%\ganttlink[m-b]{6}{4}{7}{5}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

your Gantt chart would look something like:

[image]

**Update: Solution for `pgfgantt 4.0`**

As is stated in [Missing number treated as zero in gantttitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163640/missing-number-treated-as-zero-in-gantttitle), last version of `pgfgantt` is not completely backwards compatible. And now `ganttchar` needs two mandatory arguments

```
\begin{ganttchar}[options]{<start tss>}{<end tss>}
```

Therefore, previous example should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{1}{50} % 50 weeks
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\   
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\    
\ganttbar{Task 2}{5}{6} \\    
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{6} \\    
\ganttbar{Task 3}{7}{11}
%\ganttlink{4}{2}{5}{3}
%\ganttlink[b-m]{6}{3}{6}{4}
%\ganttlink[m-b]{6}{4}{7}{5}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: above code is not working

Comment: @MickyK A new solution for last `pgfgantt` version has been added.

Answer (score 3):

[fr] tu peux jouer sur l'échelle de la figure
s'il y a des noeuds, il faudra aussi ajouter transform shape mais cela risque de ne plus être très joli

[en] you can play on the global scale of the figure
if there are knots, it will also add `transform shape`  but this may not be very pretty

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/8cm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/8cm,transform shape]
\node [rectangle,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=3cm,draw]{aaa};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those who look at this question recently, the later versions of `pgfgantt` exposed the `expand chart` parameter. You can set that parameter to whatever works for you. For example:

```
  \begin{ganttchart}[
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    hgrid,
    vgrid,
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    time slot unit=month]{2021-10}{2023-5}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
    \ganttbar{the task}{2022-1}{2022-2}
  \end{ganttchart}
```

See `2.3 The Canvas` in the [documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

One partial solution seems to use `x unit` and `y unit` to shrink the size of the time slots. This solves my first question.

I will wait for any potential answer for my second question. :)