# Compile-error using pgfgant:: "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm trying to compile a tex file containing performance analysisdata I recieve from an application. However the compiler fails with 2 errors. The first seems to because of a deprecated function in "group peaks", but the second one I really can't figure out.

Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage[empty]{fullpage} 
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview} 
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1mm} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{preview} 
\noindent \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ 
\noindent \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,x unit=0.122699cm,group left shift=0, group right  shift=0, group peaks={0}{}{.4}]{163} \\ 
\gantttitlelist{0, ..., 162}{1} \\ 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=brown}]{Title1}{47.528000}{55.143002} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{31.235001}{38.120998} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{15.351000}{22.355000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=purple}]{}{39.223000}{46.444000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{23.455999}{30.150000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{140.309998}{146.031998} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{1.048000}{6.955000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{132.285995}{139.251007} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{154.936005}{161.061005} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{147.087006}{153.880005} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=gray}]{}{56.182999}{64.136002} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{162.119003}{162.858994} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{8.086000}{14.280000} 
\\ 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{Title2}{1.000000}{0.000000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=purple}]{}{31.209000}{30.209000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{147.063004}{146.063004} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{23.430000}{22.430000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{140.283997}{139.283997} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{8.040000}{7.040000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=purple}]{}{162.095993}{161.095993} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{154.912003}{153.912003} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=gray}]{}{47.504002}{46.504002} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=brown}]{}{39.195999}{38.195999} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{132.248001}{131.248001} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{15.324000}{14.324000} 
\\ 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{Title3}{163.306000}{162.858002} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{24.966999}{30.149000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{40.833000}{46.442001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{57.873001}{64.134003} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{32.761002}{38.118999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{148.289993}{153.878006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{2.729000}{6.953000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{156.117996}{161.059998} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{141.552994}{146.031006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{9.573000}{14.279000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{49.120998}{55.140999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{133.998001}{139.246994} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{16.949001}{22.354000} 
\\ 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{Title4}{24.971001}{23.975000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{141.557007}{140.612000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{9.577000}{8.646000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{40.838001}{39.984001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{2.743000}{1.982000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{148.294006}{147.427994} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{49.125000}{48.222000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{134.003006}{133.005997} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{156.121994}{155.128006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{32.765999}{31.770000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{57.876999}{56.945000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{16.954000}{16.211000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{163.309006}{162.455994} 
\\ 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{Title5}{47.528999}{48.119999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{147.087006}{147.289001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{23.455999}{23.966000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{140.309998}{140.550995} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{31.235001}{31.760000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{56.182999}{56.872002} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{39.223000}{39.832001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{15.351000}{15.947000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{132.285995}{132.996994} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{8.086000}{8.572000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{162.119003}{162.304001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{1.057000}{1.728000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{154.936005}{155.117004} 
\\ 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{Title6}{133.998993}{133.003006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{16.949001}{15.953000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{9.574000}{8.577000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{24.966999}{23.969999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{156.117996}{155.121002} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{49.122002}{48.125000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{40.833000}{39.838001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{2.738000}{1.742000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{141.552994}{140.557007} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{57.873001}{56.875999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{163.306000}{162.309006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{148.291000}{147.294006} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{32.762001}{31.766001} 
\\ 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=gray}]{Title7}{57.873001}{56.873001} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{132.285995}{131.285995} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{133.998001}{132.998993} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{140.309998}{139.309998} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{141.552994}{140.552994} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{147.087006}{146.087006} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{148.289993}{147.291000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{1.057000}{0.057000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{2.738000}{1.738000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{8.086000}{7.086000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=red}]{}{9.573000}{8.574000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{15.351000}{14.351000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{154.936005}{153.936005} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=blue}]{}{16.949001}{15.949000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{156.117996}{155.117996} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{23.455999}{22.455999} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=green}]{}{24.966999}{23.966999} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{31.235001}{30.235001} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{32.761002}{31.761999} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=purple}]{}{39.223000}{38.223000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{162.119003}{161.119003} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=purple}]{}{40.833000}{39.833000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=pink}]{}{163.306000}{162.306000} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=brown}]{}{47.528000}{46.528999} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=brown}]{}{49.122002}{48.122002} 
\ganttgroup[group/.style={fill=gray}]{}{56.182999}{55.182999} 
\\ 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{Title8}{138.634003}{137.901001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{140.147003}{139.238007} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{23.274000}{22.344000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{21.937000}{21.500000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{20.476999}{20.094000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{54.556999}{54.109001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{18.927000}{18.236000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{56.007999}{55.132000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{15.183000}{14.270000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{13.981000}{13.608000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{142.934006}{142.238007} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{12.281000}{11.686000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{145.684998}{145.059998} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{146.848999}{146.022003} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{7.880000}{6.944000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{6.772000}{6.227000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{5.462000}{4.873000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{44.400002}{43.702999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{4.276000}{3.618000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{42.715000}{42.160000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{47.348999}{46.432999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{37.554001}{37.081001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{150.126999}{149.408997} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{151.811996}{151.171997} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{153.309998}{152.776993} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{}{154.776001}{153.865005} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=purple}]{}{45.930000}{45.337002} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{35.976002}{35.592999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{34.471001}{33.828999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{59.768002}{58.973999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{61.529999}{60.803001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{63.355999}{63.120998} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=gray}]{}{64.994003}{64.125000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=pink}]{}{38.937000}{38.110001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{157.796005}{157.130997} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{159.300995}{158.682999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{160.738998}{160.151001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{161.968994}{161.050003} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{31.059000}{30.139999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{29.782000}{29.249001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{51.089001}{50.363998} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{28.235001}{27.903999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=brown}]{}{52.856998}{53.022999} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=green}]{}{26.718000}{26.068001} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{11.033000}{10.341000} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{135.613007}{134.841003} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{}{137.276001}{137.087997} 
\ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=red}]{}{144.302002}{143.595001} 
\end{ganttchart} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{preview} 
\end{document}
```

Here's what the errors say:
 - ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfgantt/group peaks', to which you passed '{0}{}{.4}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... }
 - ! Missing number, treated as zero.\protect }

To sum up, 2 questions:

- What should I replace group peaks with?
- Why causes the "Missing number, treated as zero" error ?

I have tried compiling with Texmaker, MikTex and Texworks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: duplicate/helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163640/21344 The current `pgfgantt` package requires 2 mandatory arguments to the `ganttchart` environment; the manual states that it is _not_ fully downward-compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ptional argument `group peaks`, there are only `group peaks width` and  `group peaks height`. And the environment requires two mandatory arguments:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,x unit=0.122699cm,
       group left shift=0,
       group right shift=0,
       group peaks width=.4]{1}{163}
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that the script was written for v3 of the pgfgantt, and I was using v4. I will re-write the code to give the same output.