# Gantt chart is going to beyond the page boundary

Tags: graphics, floats, packages, pgfgantt, charts

I draw a gantt chart under the figure but it is going to beyond the boundary of page. I show my code below;

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}


\begin{landscape}
\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{gantt}[xunitlength=1cm,fontsize=\large,titlefontsize=\large,drawledgerline=true]{13}{32}
\begin{ganttitle}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{September}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{October}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{November}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{December}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{January - 14}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{February}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{March}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{April}}{4}

\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle}
\titleelement{\LARGE \textbf{Weeks}}{32}
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
\end{ganttitle}
\ganttbar{Litreature Review}{2}{17}
\ganttbar{Project Plan}{5}{10}
\ganttbar{Field Survey}{15}{3}
\ganttbar{Data Collection}{20}{3}
\ganttbar{Database Design}{15}{5}
\ganttbar{Framework Design}{}{}
\ganttbar{Prototype}{}{}
\ganttbar{Implementation}{}{}
\ganttbar{Testing}{}{}
\ganttbar{Deployment}{}{}
\end{gantt}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{center}
 \end{figure}
```

The output of this code is give in the image.......
[image]
 Please tell me how can I set my gantt chart in boundary of page.

Comment: Without a MWE, the easiest thing I can find is [ignasi's answer to "How to make pgfgantt scale to specific widths in the page? (ex. textwidth)"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59041/3345)

Comment: You can use \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{} instead of scalebox{0.6}{}.