# Dimension too large in pgfgantt

Tags: beamer, pgfgantt

I am trying to create a gantt chart using pgfgantt.

Below is the 'sample' code I'm using

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
 hgrid,
 vgrid,
 x unit=18mm,
 time slot format=little-endian
 ]{9.6.2014}{1.2.2015}
 \gantttitlecalendar*{9.6.2014}{1.2.2015}{
 month=shortname
 }
 \end{ganttchart}
```

when I try to compile it in TeXworks, this happened

> Dimension too large.

When I try smaller date duration, this code works. But I really need this 'long' date duration for my gantt chart.

I don't know how to resize this just enough for a beamer presentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your problem is related with [dimension-too-large](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118487/dimension-too-large). You can solve it using a `x unit` lower than `13mm`. But even then, will need to use a [`\resizebox`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59041/1952) command to fit the chart into a beamer frame. `12mm x 237 days` will result in a  at least 2844 mm wide Gantt chart.

Answer (score 4):

`Dimension too large` error means that you are trying to calculate some operation with a result larger that what TeX can manage.

I don't know what can produce this result, but you are trying to draw a calendar wider than 4284 mm (18mm x 238 days).

After some tests, `x unit=12mm` solves the error but unless you use `\resizebox`,
the calendar won't fit into a `beamer` slide. Even then the result is useless.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{ganttchart}[
 hgrid,
 vgrid,
 x unit=12mm,   %<-----------------
 time slot format=little-endian
 ]{9.6.2014}{1.2.2015}
 \gantttitlecalendar*{9.6.2014}{1.2.2015}{
 month=shortname
 }
 \end{ganttchart}%}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

The result without `\resizebox` looks:

[image]

and with `resizebox`:

[image]