# Why does PGFgantt struggle with a too large dimension?

Tags: pgfgantt

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    today label={Heute},
    today={\the\year-\the\month-\the\day},
    time slot format=isodate,
    progress=today,
    x unit=0.1mm,
    ]{2022-07-27}{2023-08-10}
    \ganttgroup{My Action}{2022-07-27}{2023-08-09}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

and it produces: `Dimension too large. ...ttgroup{My Action}{2022-07-27}{2023-08-09}`, which initially led me to [Dimension too large in pgfgantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209583/dimension-too-large-in-pgfgantt), but as you can see I reduced the `x unit=0.1mm` and it did not change. The image produced is OK, except for the scaling of the progress, which just does not match:
[image]

Comment: well pgfgantt should better first divide and then multiply , so do `/ 100 * \gtt@progress` instead of `* \gtt@progress / 100`.  But one can't simply patch the command. If you are daring (and probably I will be sent to hell for this suggestion) you could try `\renewcommand\pgfmathsetmacro[2]{\edef#1{\fpeval{#2}}}`.

Comment: Even if you are coming to hell it works @UlrikeFischer. Why do you come to hell, what is so bad about this patch?

Comment: well it redefines a rather central pgf command, that is used in many places, and I have no real idea if it will continue to work in all of them.

Comment: Understood @UlrikeFischer, I will hopefully remember that once it creates an issue. ;-)