# Progress bars stuck in pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, pgfgantt

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour with progress bars in a `little-endian` format `ganttchart` environment. For example, with the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
expand chart=30cm,
time slot format=little-endian
]{01-10-2023}{01-12-2024}

        \ganttbar[inline,progress=10]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=20]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=30]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=40]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=50]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=60]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=70]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\
        \ganttbar[inline,progress=80]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}\\

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I find the following output:
[image]

The displayed progress bar reaches a maximum, which is not the requested progress. The log contains the following error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 
    
l.20 ...ine,progress=50]{}{01-11-2023}{01-10-2024}
                                                  \\  
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

This error is repeated for all the affected ganttbar calls. The problem persists for all reasonable `expand chart` sizes I can think to try (i.e. cm-scale), and all reasonable chart limits (i.e. year-scale). I cannot reproduce the problem for charts measured in integers (e.g. `\begin{ganttchart}[...]{1}{5}` etc).
All help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 30cm is reasonable?  The rest has to do with pgfmath which uses 1pt for 1.

Comment: Many thanks @JohnKormylo, so I guess e.g. 10cm is more reasonable for `expand chart`? Either way, following the trail of pgfmath, it seems [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209583/dimension-too-large-in-pgfgantt#:~:text=Dimension%20too%20large%20error%20means,that%20what%20TeX%20can%20manage.) might be helpful. However after lots of experimentation with `x unit` I cannot find any change: the progress is still stuck at 50%.

Comment: I've never used pgfgantt, but you can create a progress bar using only `\framebox` and `\rule`.